# What is the best way for system call hooking for Linux 2.6.36 or newer for my LKM?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm looking for a professional way which code to be transferable among platforms and multiple Linux versions as well as very readable.
Please note that I read "Linux Kernel: System calll hooking example" question in this stackoverflow site.

I think there are two ways.

1. Change the hooking table in the source code itself such as linux-2.6.36/include/asm-generic/unistd.h.
   In this case, the code must be not compatible as Linux version changes and looks not professional to me.
2. Change the system call table dynamically by mudule_init() in my LKM.
   In this case, there are two issues for me.
   -One is, how to know “sys_call_table” address as the symbol isn’t exported anymore from linux 2.6.x.
   Instead, using physical address like below by capturing the address in System.map isn't appropriate as I need to check the address every time I build the code.
   -The second issue I think is that, changing the table requires to make the page of sys_call_table be writable.
   I know how to this as I’m using ARM cortex and know how to control the system register of ARM cortex.
   However, I’m curious if this is the right way as the code isn’t also compatible to the other platforms.

Comment: There is no good way of hooking system calls. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I would develop a secure Linux, and make it easy maintenance or easy understandable. Note: The secure Linux module will be LKM.

Comment: Will the “sys_call_table” physical address keep change?

Comment: For example, if I use the statement like "sys_call_table = (void*)0xc061e4e0;", will be value 0xc061e4e0 keep change when I rebuilt the kernel? If then, I think it is very difficult to maintain the code works.